# What is the plural of "passion fruit"?

Tags: grammatical-number, compounds, north-american-english

I know we can use both *fruit* and *fruits* (countable noun and uncountable noun):

1. The fruit began to rot.
2. The fruits began to rot.

What has confused me is *passion fruit* because it has the word *fruit* in it!  Is *passion fruit* a noun, or is it an adjective (*passion*) and a noun (*fruit*)? I assume the former but I am not sure because of the singular/plural forms of *mouse/mice* (in regards to the animal and computer equipment — same word, but different meanings). This is why I am questioning my own ears when I say the following out loud:

3. There are many passion fruit in this bowl.
4. There are many passion fruits in this bowl.

I have read [Is using "fruits" as the plural of "fruit" acceptable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25147/is-using-fruits-as-the-plural-of-fruit-acceptable) which is nearly a dupe other than it doesn’t specifically state by region, and although *fruit* is used as an example I’m not sure if it applies as I’m talking about a different noun.

So my two questions are

1. Are all four examples acceptable in English?
2. Are all four examples acceptable in *American* English?

Comment: Close parallels are **kiwi fruit**, **sharon fruit**, **star fruit** and **ugli fruit**. Differing only in that it is a single word is **grapefruit**. I can't say that I have ever heard **grapefruits**  and rarely, if ever, heard the plural form of the others. I would say that that **passion fruit** is its own plural. By the way I'm a British English native speaker.

Comment: It's not nearly a dupe, it's a dupe. The accepted answer is "Fruit can be used as an uncountable noun or a countable noun in which case the plural form would be fruits. In the example sentence, both usages are acceptable." As part of the compound "passion fruit" the same applies (your example being one where it's countable, though).