# "Lemons are fruits which are sour" vs "A lemon is a fruit which is sour"

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences, grammatical-number

1. Lemons are fruits which are sour.
2. A lemon is a fruit which is sour.

Are these two sentences interchangeable? To me the first sentence looks awkward. 
If there is any difference between the two then please explain it.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25147/is-using-fruits-as-the-plural-of-fruit-acceptable

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways of saying essentially the same thing:

1. Lemons are sour fruit(s).
2. A lemon is a sour fruit.
3. The lemon is a sour fruit.

(Notice that I converted your relative clause into an attributive adjective, just for simplicity.)

In each case, your purpose is to tell us something about lemons *generally*, not about some particular lemons. You are talking about the *type* of fruit. This is called a *general statement*. All three types of sentences can be used to convey general statements (see [here](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/7412971896) for a reference to Alexander's *Longman English Grammar*).

The first uses a *plural* (also known as *zero article*), the second an *indefinite article*, and the third a *definite article*. All are usually acceptable.

In your case, the awkwardness of (1)—insofar as there is some—is caused by the word "fruit". Typically, this sentence would be rendered as something like:

4. Lemons are a type of sour fruit.