# Pork Is or Pork Are

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm trying to say that there's black pork, cheap pork, premium pork, etc.

Hence,

1) Not all pork is created equal?
2) Not all pork are created equal?

I understand that plural of pork is still pork. But in this case, does the inclusion of "all" warrant an "are"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One might say "Not all porks are created equal."

Comment: It's not true that the plural of *pork* is *pork*. *Pork* is usually used as a "mass noun", which means it doesn't have a plural: the singular form is used to refer to small or large quantities.

Comment: This is similar to fuel vs fuels. If there's more than one type of pork (maybe from different types of pig, or different cuts) then you could use porks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is using "fruits" as the plural of "fruit" acceptable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25147/is-using-fruits-as-the-plural-of-fruit-acceptable). The whole countification issue is well addressed, especially the 'count usage for kinds of' usage (coffees / beers / milks / rices ...). As well as the 'portions of' usage. Essentially, then most particular examples are general reference.

Answer (score 6):

*Pork* is not the plural of *pork*.

*Pork*, when referring to the meat, is not a case like *sheep* or *aircraft* where the plural form is the same as the singular—although *[swine](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/swine)*, the animal from which pork is derived, can be.

> A deer was getting into the garden, so we put up a taller fence.
>   Three deer were captured on the wildlife camera.

Rather, *pork* being a type of meat is an uncountable noun (i.e. *mass noun*), like other words for undifferentiated materials or qualities, like *cotton*, or *satisfaction*. A mass noun is considered singular, with no plural form, and always takes singular verb agreement, so

> Not all pork is created equal.

is the standard formulation.

That said, when referring to specific varieties or portions of that material, uncountable nouns can often be treated as countable, and thus do have a plural form which takes plural concord. For example, *beer* as a substance is a mass noun, as in *they poured beer into pitchers*. I can, however, say *I had four beers* grammatically if I mean to say I had four glasses of beer, or that I tried four different kinds of beer. Which meaning I intend will depend on context.

It is not common to use *pork* this way, but if the context is very clear, *porks* is acceptable. For example, waitstaff at a dinner function where pork, fish, and vegetarian dishes are offered might ask the kitchen for "three porks," meaning three servings of pork. A journalist might write of *Spam and other highly processed porks*, or contrast farming methods of *North American porks and East Asian porks*, and so forth. And in this restricted usage, *not all porks are created equal* would be acceptable as well.